# position: sticky not working! within FLEXBOX

Tags: html, css

my position: sticky div is not working!

I have set body and HTML **without** height: 100%.

app has position: relative.
main has position: relative; display: flex; flex-direction: row; height: 100%; overflow: visible;

then within main, i have .left and .right with position: relative; display: flexbox;
inside .left, i have 2 children elements: one is not-sticky, one is sticky.
I DON'T KNOW HOW TO MAKE THE STICKY ONE WORK!

```
<div class="app">
<main>
  <div class="left">
    <div class="not-sticky"></div>
    <div class="sticky"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</main>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your CSS

Comment: Can You please add the CSS code which you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.
If you don't set `align-items` property to your `main` tag, then the childs `.left` and `.right` has the same height.

So the `.sticky` div works properly.

```css
main {
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.not-sticky {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.sticky {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.right {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
<main>
  <div class="left">
    <div class="not-sticky"></div>
    <div class="sticky">It stops at top 0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</main>
</div>
```

Comment: How could you possibly give an answer without seeing OP's CSS?

Comment: It's the method to solve the issue, not the exact solution. I think @thao can solve his issue with my answer.

Comment: And, his CSS is in his question.

Comment: thank you. it is what i want to achieve, but since i got body, html overflow-x: hidden; width: 100% it is not working.

Comment: Do you mean `8px margin` in `body`?

Comment: Don't need `width: 100%` to HTML.